Data classification doesn't work with BERT model
I need to train model with input CSV, that has error message and error classification. Then when tested with just error message, it should automatically classify.
I've used BERT model and this is the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

# Load the training data and print the columns
training_data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\foobar\\Training Data.xlsx")
print(training_data.columns)  # Print to verify column names

# Ensure column names are stripped of spaces
training_data.columns = training_data.columns.str.strip()

# Use the correct column names based on the output
error_messages = training_data["Error Message"].dropna()
error_classification = training_data["Error Classification"].dropna()

# Ensure that the lengths are consistent
min_length = min(len(error_messages), len(error_classification))
error_messages = error_messages.iloc[:min_length]
error_classification = error_classification.iloc[:min_length]

# Convert labels to numeric using LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
error_classification_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(error_classification)

# Split the data into training and validation sets
train_messages, val_messages, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(
    error_messages, error_classification_encoded, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

# Initialize BERT tokenizer and model
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Preprocess the text data
def preprocess_text(texts):
    return tokenizer(
        texts.tolist(),
        max_length=128,
        truncation=True,
        padding='max_length',
        return_tensors='tf'
    )

train_tokens = preprocess_text(train_messages)
val_tokens = preprocess_text(val_messages)

# Define the model architecture
input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')
attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128,), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask')

# Wrap the BERT model call in a Lambda layer and specify the output shape
bert_output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: bert_model(input_ids=x[0], attention_mask=x[1]).pooler_output,
    output_shape=(768,)
)([input_ids, attention_mask])

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(bert_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)  # Add dropout for regularization
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(label_encoder.classes_), activation="softmax")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, attention_mask], outputs=output)

# Use a lower learning rate for fine-tuning
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=2e-5)  # Lower learning rate

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Convert labels to NumPy arrays
train_labels = np.array(train_labels).astype(int)
val_labels = np.array(val_labels).astype(int)

# Add callbacks for better training control
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, restore_best_weights=True),  # Stop if validation loss doesn't improve for 3 epochs
    ModelCheckpoint('best_model.keras', save_best_only=True)  # Save only the best model
]

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    [train_tokens['input_ids'], train_tokens['attention_mask']],
    train_labels,
    validation_data=([val_tokens['input_ids'], val_tokens['attention_mask']], val_labels),
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=16,  # Add batch size if appropriate
    callbacks=callbacks
)

# Load the best model before making predictions
model.load_weights('best_model.keras')

# Load the testing data
testing_data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\foobar\\Testing Data.xlsx")
test_messages = testing_data["Error Message"]

# Preprocess the testing data
test_tokens = preprocess_text(test_messages)

# Perform predictions on the testing data
predictions = model.predict([test_tokens['input_ids'], test_tokens['attention_mask']])
predicted_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

# Decode the labels back to original format
decoded_predictions = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predicted_labels)

# Update the output CSV with the predicted error classifications
output_data = pd.DataFrame({"Error Message": test_messages, "Error Classification": decoded_predictions})
output_data.to_csv("C:\\Users\\foobar\\Output.csv", index=False)

Training Input contains, HTTP Error message and classification: (SAMPLE)

And Testing Input is this:

But the Output.csv comes out incorrect for 5** error, it shows "Client error" incorrectly.

